# Correct way to render @ContentChildren QueryList changes

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, angular8

I have an issue with rendering components
Here is example of code.

```
<my-component>
  <ng-template *ngFor="let item of data">
    <child-component>
      <div>
        {{ data.title }}
      </div>
    </child-component>
  </ng-template>
</my-component>
```

in the my-component.ts

```
@ContentChildren(TemplateRef) template: QueryList<TemplateRef<any>>;
```

```
ngAfterContentInit(): void {
  this.template.forEach(item => {
     const template = this.viewTemplateRef.createEmbeddedView(item);
     template.detectChanges();
  });
}
```

When i push something into data i need to display a new child component. If i try to do something like that:

```
this.template.changes.subscribe((result) => {
    this.template.forEach(item => {
       this.viewTemplateRef.createEmbeddedView(item);
    });
});
```

I've got infinity loop. What the correct way to do this?

Here is example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8pvrhq

Comment: can u provide a demo code on stackblitz.com. This question needs more clarification

Comment: If you want to tell child components that they should be refresh you can add `this.changeDetectorRef.detecChanges()` after push new item to the data array. Is ng-template necessary?

Comment: @ShashankVivek https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8pvrhq?file=src%2Fapp%2Fcomponents%2Fcomponent-a%2Fcomponent-a.component.ts

Comment: @KamilAugustyniak please have to look my example https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8pvrhq

Comment: Why do you want to use there `ViewContainerRef`?

Comment: I don't understand your example. I think there is a lot of unnecessary logic. I've cleaned your code. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-p8vjqs I hope that it a little help you.

Comment: @KamilAugustyniak in my project i need my struct. I'm develop a new library for using maps. so my main component - it's map, and child components its markers. somethink like https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-google-maps-demo?file=app%2Fapp.component.html   as you see they are using my way) i to do somethink similar for my library)

Comment: @IgorZinchenko : will take a look at it in sometime :) Thanks for the update

Answer (score 0):

So that is impossible, I can't use ng-template for passing data. 
Thanks for anyone for the support!

```
<my-component>
  <child-component *ngFor="let item of data">
    <div>
      {{ data.title }}
    </div>
  </child-component>
</my-component>
```

Solved for me.